# Necessity of storing variables in Firebase Database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am wondering about how necessary it is to store variables in the realtime firebase database if I want all Users at access the same dynamic variable.

So for instance, I have a arraylist that stores the list of open games, and if I want this list to update in realtime for every user should this List in firebase realtime database?

Sorry for the simplicity of the question

Comment: Did you find my answer useful @brentB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it may be a simple question, but it surely pops in head of everyone, once.

I think for updating any list dynamically in real time, would require you to access any kind of database.

It is not necessary to have it on Firebase database, but any database online, that can tell every open instance of your app that the list has to be updated at a particular instant.

The main reason of why you need it to be on database is updating it in real time and that too dynamically.

If it's not dynamic, meaning the content that you need, can be hardcoded then one way would be placing everything you need in your code and using timer or something like that to fire at particular moments to update things in your app.

Also that aside, sorting, storing and changing data is much simpler using a database, which also becomes one more reason for you to use a database like Firebase to keep content of your app that has to be updated frequently in real time.

You can know more about database in this [Google link, I found.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=24&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjoxL7sw6jeAhXK66QKHZTyB5cQFjAXegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.softwaretestingclass.com%2Fwhat-is-database-and-why-do-we-need-them%2F&usg=AOvVaw37izeAaUIX89FLLHsbfUvm)

Comment: Sorry for late response, I went to bed early last night. This answer helps me a lot, thank you!

Comment: @brentB no worries, glad to help. Cheers! :)